# What should I do if my system boots up,runs normally after then but nothing is displayed on screen?

Tags: boot, freeze, display

Well there has been a problem with my PC since few days.

My system with a flat screen,2 RAMS,Intel Motherboard,No Video or Graphics Card,2 Hard disk- One of 80 GB and another of 500 GB,Windows 7 Ultimate.All data on my system is safe.I transferred some data from my friends' external Hard drive few days back so I think some virus has attacked my system.

I am going to explain what happens.

When I press start button on my CPU,it normally starts and the fan inside on the motherboard is running but the fan in PSU starts  like zrrrrr..... zrrrrrr..... zrrrrr..... for atleast a minute and then it runs normally.

Now the desktop starts for 4-6 seconds and turns yellow which means nothing shows up on screen.Still the system is running.

When I press Alt,Ctrl,Del simultaneously the desktop starts again for 4-6 seconds means the same problem.

When I take out CMOS battery and insert it again-the same problem.

When I interchange both the RAMs(1 RAM of 2GB and another one of 512Mb)-again the same problem.

Few days back prior to this problem,the mouse was not able to work and the screen was facing problems of displaying nothing and displaying normally(this happened almost 3 times in every 30 mins)while watching movie(Pulp Fiction-wow I loved this movie) and doing other tasks.And I was working with just arrow keys the mouse was not working.Last night fortunately when I started the system anyhow with pressing Alt,Ctrl,Del and F8,F9,F10,F10 all at once.It started and I noticed all the data were safe and mouse was working properly and keyboard was ok too.And Again the same problem happened.

(I don't know how to do BIOS settings by pressing F8,or F10 etc)

What should I do?

Comment: If the PSU fan is making a funny noise, that indicates that either the fan itself is failing (or at least clogged with dust) or the 12V supply in the PSU is failing.  Your other symptoms would be consistent with a 12V failure.

Comment: You seem to have jumped straight from POST to desktop without any logos, messages, or other things being displayed in between.  Is this truly an accurate and complete description of your computer's behaviour?  How does the mouse sprite behave on this desktop?

Comment: Sounds more like a graphics failure/fault 'desktop starts for 4-6 seconds and turns yellow'.

Comment: @DanH I will check it again,thanks.@JdeBp Yes this is the accurate description until,let me find more details,I will try it soon,Thankx.@HaydnWVN I didn't get you?

Comment: The system could possibly be shutting down components as a fail safe for overheating. Seen regularly with CPU and GPU's (on board or otherwise) overheating. An irregular power flow could also have damaged the motherboard, resulting in USB port failure along with intermittent. Alternatively just check your VGA cable.

Comment: @HimanshuPrasad You're welcome. Hope I helped.

Comment: @DwayneHinterlang well the system is normal now and display is normal but after a while within 10 minutes it again displays nothing and mouse it still not working after my system boots up.

Comment: @HimanshuPrasad For your mouse problem, see if it works in a different USB port if not then try a different USB device in the same port and see if it works. If a different device works then your mouse is possibly damaged, if the device does not work then your motherboard is possibly damaged, in which case getting a PCI USB Controller would be the simplest solution. Your display not working after ten minutes could be overheating, to check this run a hardware monitoring software to check the temperature, if the temperature is stable then your motherboard is faulty and needs to be replaced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Have you try changing your power supply?
- Boot in safe mode?
- replacing your monitor cable?

To clear your BIOS, try using the jumper instead of taking out the battery. Don't forget to reconfig your BIOS after resetting it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer chmod.can u tell me how to reconfig BIOS?

Comment: I can't really tell you how to config your BIOS as I don't know your initial configuration. But here are some guideline. 

1. Choose the correct startup disk
2. choose correct SATA setting, (compatibility,AHCI,RAID)
3. Boot order

By the way to get, to enter BIOS setting, press del key during POST

Comment: the problem of displaying content on screen has been resolved by doing some changes in power supply connection,now it working alright but still the mouse isn't working and again the same problem happens when I leave my system untouched for almost 10 mins.

Comment: Great to hear that the screen problem have been solved. As for the mouse, did you try a different mouse?

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify if when transferring data from your friends hard drive you unplugged anything **internal** to your PC?

The symptoms you have are very general but could be related to your Graphics card failing, overheating, or not getting enough power. You have an onboard graphics card - are you able to disable it and test with a different/new PCI-e graphics card?

Comment: Sorry I will not able be able to justify what I have written here.No I am not able to disable it as I havn't done it before.

Comment: Did you take the side off your PC when you transferred data for your friend? Or did you plug his/her drive into an external USB caddy/enclosure?

Comment: I plugged his drive into external USB.

Comment: Ok then we can eliminate the possibilty of an internal cable being disturbed/unplugged/damaged from the equation. What did you mean about the screen turning yellow? Can you unplug your monitor cable to check for any damage/dust/dirt and then replug it back in to eliminate that, thanks :)

Comment: I meant when the screen starts there's a green light which is power button of screen,for yellow I mean when nothing displays on the screen.Now the problem has resolved but mouse it not able to work and the when I leave my desktop doing nothing it again displays nothing(nearly after 10 minutes-which means the power button of screen turns yellow) so I think there's still some problem with it.

Comment: After 10 minutes of non activity causing the screen to go onto 'StandBy' (the orange light as opposed to green) would indicate a power profile setting turning off the screen or hybernating the PC. It could also be the screen saver initiating one of the 'Open GL' screensavers which utilise 3D elements of the graphics card, which due to a fault overheats or crashes causing the machine to turn off/hang/go into standby.